# Retrieving data from firebase takes too much time

Tags: android

I want to retrieve Firebase data to textview, imageview and listview. My example database structure has many other nodes like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JURr3.png

So I add username to a textview, profile photo to imageview, birthdate to a textview and there are many other nodes like messages and other usernames (in an activity).

It takes to much time to retrieve data to each view and then it shows all the data at the same time. It doesn't show each data simultaneously after loading but shows all requested data to all views after loading.

How do I get a view after a view loading and showing?

UI of that activity after fetching data. (Birthdate and some data haven't added yet).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRX0O.png

While retrieving with default image and text:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEhv9.png

Comment: Did you save the photo of the imageview as bytes or you store just file path of the photo? If you save the whole image as bytes, it is normal to take longer time for the system to process all this data.

Comment: Did you also try to use multiple threads? Did you try using Background Processing?

Comment: Try creating objects and store all your data inside it.

Comment: @Beasteca, yeah, I save it as byte code.

Comment: @dnsiv ,can you give me an example? Please...

Comment: Google AsynchTask, Loader, Services, Threads. They handle heavy tasks in the background. It's also possible to let your code work more efficient if you parallelize a big workload of tasks.

Comment: @user9266642 I see from one of your replies that you are storing bytecode in your database, which is a very poor way of storing image files and hence it is bound to take time. Instead of doing that use firebase storage to store the image file and then save the image path inside your database. From there, you can easily use ImageView to display the image.

Comment: @user9266642 Just get the file path of your image and save it into your database. This way it will be 10000 easier for your DB for the system to handle the data transfer. After you save your file path just query it back once you need it, find the image in your local phone storage and display it. Technically you are not saving the image, but storing where it is located.

Comment: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

Use Sqlite as a local database to store your data as well as using Firebase Realtime Database. Every time data is loaded for the first time it will also be stored in the local database. So the next time you open the app you would see the results you expect.

Then if you are using Firebase Realtime Database as a backend, use the Firebase Offline Data Handling feature.

Comment: I agree with your opinion about sqlite. Even every professional apps like instagram use this feature. That's why it's cache size is too much and also it is an offline readable app. I also want this feature in my app too. I'm not so familiar with sqlite, so can you please suggest me any tutorial on "firebase with sqlite". Thanks!

Comment: Firebase db is different from SQlite if u want to combine them both then store that in the local db first than use Read statement of sqlite to fetch the data and send that data to Firebase. Google search: How to send data from sqlite to Firebase you would get good contents

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are feting data, ideally this should be the set of steps that you should be doing.

1. Fetch all the data(all children data as well) from that node and put it in a list.
2. Pass the data to a RecyclerView and populate it this was there wont be any lag.

This is an example code to fetch all the child nodes

```
myQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // TODO: Add to list to send it to recyclerview
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());     
    }
});
```

Hopefully, this will help you.

Comment: No...the views are not in a cluster.The username is in the toolbar.The birthdate is in a dialog..so how to fetch them?

Comment: still, the same way looks like  there is some logic involved where you show the data for each item(user in your case) in a different screen

Comment: @user9266642  could you shed some more light on how the UI behaviour is there

Comment: I have added. OnActivityCreate, it retrieve all requested data and than show in views.I want is show one data  after retrieve and another one.eg. if it retrieve username first, show it and go on the others.But my activity don't show one after one but show all in the same time.So I have to wait without seeing any data in my views...

Comment: then this has to be done before the navigation, and also persist your data locally and update the DB in background

Answer (score 0):

Don't reach Firebase data directly from the client because of possible authentication and performance problems due to unintented implementation and usage of the Firestore api.

Instead, use [Firebase cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) and write a service for what you need. To call those services from the app, you can use [Firebase calls](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). You may suffer from cold boot but you can solve it with a warm up process ex. call those functions every minute with a cron job that can be set via [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/en/)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable offline data in Firebase so every time you don't need to reload from the server first. First, you populate the data from the cache source and then silently load the data from the server source.

[Enable Offline Data in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)

Comment: But i have seen that even offline data takes so much time in fetching data from chache memories.